# How to remove the comma before a post-note in citations using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

I'm managing my references using `biblatex`. Sometimes I need to write a post-note, but the citation appears with a comma (´,´). There is a way to erase it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}

%References
\begin{filecontents*}{references22.bib}
@Article{Ho_1899,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P.},
  title    = {Example article},
  year     = {1899}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references22.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite[some words]{Ho_1899}\\ %I'd like to remove the comma after the year
\parencite[some words]{Ho_1899}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\space}` will erase the comma

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
bibstyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\space}

%References
\begin{filecontents*}{references22.bib}
@Article{Ho_1899,
  author   = {Ho, Lionel and Dreyfus, J. and Boyer, J. and Lowe, T. and Bustamante, H. and Duker, P.},
  title    = {Example article},
  year     = {1899}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references22.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite[some words]{Ho_1899}\\ %I'd like to remove the comma after the year
\parencite[some words]{Ho_1899}

\end{document}
```